# SQL Server Compare rows of one table with all rows of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables which contains firstname, surname,dob.
First table has datatype as varchar for all columns and second table is varchar(50),varchar(50),datetime datatype.

```
Ex:
1st table 
fname surname dob
a       b      04/12/1948
a       b      05/08/1984

 2nd table
fname surname dob
a       b      05/08/1984
a       b      04/12/1948
```

when i do Intersect is not matching the decors (possibly b'ze of datatype)
and except give me result.

Is there any way to select all record from table 1 with matching records of table 2.

Any help much apprecciated

Comment: What is the issue, i have tried with two tables and datatype as described, i am able to get intersect records

Comment: Show expected result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **EXCEPT** and **INTERSECT** work:

```
Declare @tblA AS TABLE(
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    SurName VARCHAR(50),
    Dob VARCHAR(50)
)

Declare @tblB AS TABLE(
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    SurName VARCHAR(50),
    Dob Date
)

INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES
('a','b','04/12/1948'),
('a','b','05/08/1948')

INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES
('a','b','04/12/1948'),
('a','b','05/09/1948')

SELECT
    *
FROM @tblA
INTERSECT
SELECT
    *
FROM @tblB

SELECT
    *
FROM @tblA
EXCEPT
SELECT
    *
FROM @tblB
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fname, surname, CAST(dob AS DATETIME) AS dob FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT fname, surname, dob FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query.

```
Select * from table1 as a
Inner join table2 as b
on a.fname = b.fname and a.surname = b.surname and cast(a.dob as date)=b.dob
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM #Table1 JOIN #Table2 ON #Table2.dob = CONVERT(DATETIME,#Table1.dob,101)
```